# The first Betti Number of a directed graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, betti-numbers

Given an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$, the first Betti number of G is $|E| - |V| + k$, where $k$ is the number of connected components of $G$.
I was thinking what is the case for a directed graph $G$. Is it analogous, and the Betti number equals to the minimal number of feedback arc set (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set)?

Comment: The Betti numbers are by their origin a topological property of a graph. An undirected graph is also a CW-complex and the Betti number can also be defined as the dimension of the first homology group. From this interpretation, one would define the Betti number of a directed graph by simply ignoring the directions and treating it as an undirected graph. Maybe other definitions exist that make use of the directions but the question then becomes what your definition is supposed to do.

Comment: I understand. So there is no one agreed definition for that?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe there is and someone who knows more graph theory will point it out. That is why I wrote a comment and not an answer.